# ruby asin gem search failing on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems, amazon-product-api

I've recently moved over from the ruby-aaws gem to asin gem, which is a lot simpler to use and understand. However, I've encountered a really strange issue that's causing search failures for specific queries and only on heroku.

My code is the following:

```
require 'asin'

client = ASIN::Client.instance

client.search(:Keywords => "Shark Tale", :SearchIndex => :UnboxVideo, :ResponseGroup => :ItemAttributes)
```

When this runs on my local box, it works perfect without issue. However, when I run this on heroku, I see the following error logs:

```
REXML::ParseException: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:340:in `pull_event'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:183:in `pull'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/crack-0.4.0/lib/crack/xml.rb:203:in `parse'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/crack-0.4.0/lib/crack/xml.rb:235:in `parse'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/asin-1.1.2/lib/asin/client.rb:375:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/asin-1.1.2/lib/asin/client.rb:197:in `search'
(irb):223:in `irb_binding'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:86:in `eval'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:86:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/context.rb:380:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:492:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:624:in `signal_status'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:489:in `block in eval_input'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `loop'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `each_top_level_statement'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:488:in `eval_input'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:397:in `block in start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:396:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:396:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
...
Exception parsing
Line: 1
Position: 30315
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
Actor><Actor>Matthew Broderick</Actor><Actor>Patrick Warburton</Actor><Actor>J
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:439:in `rescue in pull_event'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:331:in `pull_event'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:183:in `pull'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/crack-0.4.0/lib/crack/xml.rb:203:in `parse'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/crack-0.4.0/lib/crack/xml.rb:235:in `parse'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/asin-1.1.2/lib/asin/client.rb:375:in `call'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/asin-1.1.2/lib/asin/client.rb:197:in `search'
from (irb):223
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This fails around 9 out of 10 times on Heroku. I tried a few variations and some of the following variations succeed all the time:

Change the query slightly

```
client.search(:Keywords => "Shark Tales", :SearchIndex => :UnboxVideo, :ResponseGroup => :ItemAttributes)
```

Change the ResponseGroup

```
client.search(:Keywords => "Shark Tale", :SearchIndex => :UnboxVideo, :ResponseGroup => :Offers)
```

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: It looks like you're getting malformed XML back from Amazon (although that does seem unlikely). Can you set the ASIN log level to info and post the output somewhere? In particular there should be a message that says "got response=…". Something like `ASIN::Configuration.logger.level = Logger::INFO` will probably do it.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the discrepancy between my local box and heroku is with ruby version.

I'm using 1.9.3 on local box whereas my heroku setting is 2.0.0

This is a solution for 2.0.0 from the author of the asin gem
http://asin.herokuapp.com/